# Help identifying wild Irish tree

Tags: identification, trees, shrubs

I've been trying to identify this tree, found along the roadside in a hilly area of southwest Ireland (Cork). Some features:

- Small, stiff, serrated leaves that look slightly similar to holly but not as glossy
- Very dense clusters of small white flowers, very fragrant (can easily smell the tree from a few feet back)
- Pleasant smell - similar to roses
- Plant height is roughly 10-12ft high
- Found on roadside directly adjacent to brambles, elder, and gorse

I've been all over numerous identification sites/apps/books, google image search, etc. and have yet to see a similar flower. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Are you able to add a photo of the whole plant - seeing overall growth habit is also very helpful for ID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at *Olearia macrodonta* (New Zealand Holly). According to [this](https://www.floralimages.co.uk/page.php?taxon=olearia_macrodonta,1) website, it's "Very well established throughout West Cork now."

Comment: Omg you found it! Thank you so much!!